# My Instagram Client Suspended

Tags: instagram-api

I've made a similar app like Instagram + Zomato when users can make a post with Image about their food, and Instagram API to show user pictures from Instagram and store it in my app it's kinda a upload alternative that you can browse your picture from Instagram gallery.

But then, my client app got suspended, I don't know why?! and I already submit the Instagram App Enforcement Appeal, but not get any replies yet.
My product owner already ask me again about the progress, and I told him that the Policies that we violating is by storing the client_id and client_secret to the DB, I'm not sure tho. I'm going to create new client app to solve this.

Have you experienced from this?

How long it takes to get replies from Instagram Support?

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you get a warning email or just got suspended?

Comment: I just got suspended, no warning email, oh before the my client told me that instagram not working, I was temporally deactive my account.